# explode column from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi every I need to get product from the database and explode it in one line of code So I can get product data and get product_properties as an array together

```
    $Product = Product::find(33);
    $properties = explode(",", ($Product ->product_properties));
```

Comment: what is product_properties?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you just want to convert `product_properties` to an array?

Comment: Why do you need this in a single line? A working solution in 2 lines, like the way you have, is perfectly fine.

Comment: is it has many relations product_properties?

Comment: all what i need is to get product from database and get product_properties  as array

Comment: you get me wrong i need to return product normally and return product_properties  as array in single line Socan i do it any help please

Comment: This could be a good use case for an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just explode `product_properties` to get an array or, you could also define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on your `Product` model.

So in `App\Product`, add the following:

```
public function getPropertiesAttribute()
{
    return explode(',', $this->product_properties); 
}
```

That's it. Now, every time you retrieve your model, you also have access to its properties in an array format by doing the following:

```
$product = Product::find(33);
$product->properties; // will output product_properties in an array format
```

Edit: If you want this `properties` (computed) field to be included in its JSON representation, for example, you need to define it in the `appends` property in your model. For example.

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['properties'];
```

Here's a working [example](https://implode.io/GyLKGG).

Comment: didn't Work  My friend

Comment: it's Worked fine

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://implode.io/GyLKGG). If you got it to work, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: but i need to return Product with it

Comment: I updated my [example](https://implode.io/GyLKGG). You can still have access to all other properties in your model. So, for example. if your product has a name `$product->name` will still work. `$product->properties` will return the array you need also.

Comment: i don't know what i say but i need to use it like   return $product;

Comment: i need to return product normally just the product_properties will return as array

Comment: i'm using it in api

Comment: Just treat it as a normal product model. If you want this computed property to be shown in your Product's JSON representation add it to the `appends` array. I updated my [example](https://implode.io/GyLKGG) again to illustrate that.

Comment: i have more than 9 columns in products is there any other way to just return array in simple         return Product::find(1);

Comment: Sure. `return Product::find(1)->properties` will return the array you want.

Comment: yes but like that i will get only array of product_properties i need to get all  product and array using         return Product::find(1);

Comment: is thire away for that ?

Comment: Maybe `return Product::find(1)->toArray();` is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mbp2yh this how normally product return http://prntscr.com/mbp2yh

Comment: Now i need the same thing but product_properties return like that http://prntscr.com/mbp3tk

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Feel free to uncheck this as the right answer.

Comment: No man you thanks alot have a nice day and thanks for thinking with me

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it doing:

```
    $properties = explode(",", (Product::find(33)->product_properties));
```

But this is poor in readability compared with your first approach.

Comment: Same result it just return  product_properties as array i need to return product as well

Comment: But you need a one line solution for all?